# Android app that sends http requests over usb

Tags: android, http, usb, ethernet

I am working on an Android app that will record GPS from multiple devices. One of these devices is a TrellisWare radio which needs to be connected to the phone via USB->Ethernet. The radio's API takes HTTP requests to retrieve the GPS data. I have scoured the interwebs trying to figure this out. I have found all sorts of stuff on usb tethering/reverse tethering, RNDIS, and Volley. I'm still lost on the best approach for sending HTTP data across the USB port. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: for something this specific you are best off contacting the provider of the radio. Are you directly connecting the radio to the phone via usb? Is the radio actually reporting itself as a ethernet connection? How do you know what address to send http requests to? these are things that should be answered by the radios documentation/support

Comment: I added the setup above: Android device -> USB -> Ethernet -> Radio. I know the radios IP address, not sure about port yet. I can ping the radio.